# SSRS Not Displaynig Columns and Values

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm practising SSRS and I'm having an weirds issue.
I'm creating a simple query where it returns 3 columns from the Product table from the Adventure Works Database.
However, the column and rows are blank. I then created another rdl, this time with the Wizard and it's working fine.
When I run my query in the query editor, the information is displayed.

Any ideas?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer.
Resizing the table seems to refresh something and the values are not been displayed.
Really weird bug. I had tried before, deleting and adding the table, closing Visual Studio, creating a new RDL.